# Many to Many Criteria Query

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, hibernate-criteria

I'm trying to implement tag functionality for a post.

I'm modeling the problem with the tables shown below:
[image]

I want to make a query to retrieve all the posts that have some particular tags. Can someone show me how this can be achieved?

Comment: Could you re-phrase your question? Do you read any tutorials like [that](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-many-to-many)? Do you read any documentation and/or API? If yes, please specify what's unclear.

Comment: Sorry for being confusing. I wanna build a query with Criteria API that gets all the posts that contain a particular list of tags.

Comment: It would be great if you *edit* question: 1. Please add about Criteria API so make it clear from question, not from comments. 2. Please add what search have you done and specify what's unclear. At this moment, it looks like you want we google for you.

Answer (score 0):

Setting up the data model correct should do the trick

```
@Entity(name = "Post")
@Table(name = "post")
public class PostJpa {

   @Id
   private Long id;

   @ManyToMany
   @JoinTable(name = "post_tag", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "postId"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id"))
   Set<TagJpa> tags;
}

@Entity(name = "Tag")
@Table(name = "tag")
public class TagJpa {

    @Id
    @Nullable
    private Long id;

    @Nullable
    private String name;

    @Nullable
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags")
    Set<PostJpa> posts;
}
```

With this you can create following simple join

```
public void getPosts() {
    CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

    CriteriaQuery<PostJpa> query = builder.createQuery(PostJpa.class);
    Root<PostJpa> root = query.from(PostJpa.class);
    Join<Object, Object> subRoot = root.join("tags", JoinType.INNER);

    query.where(builder.equal(subRoot.get("name"), builder.literal("jpa")));

    entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
}
```